# Regular expressions: Find and replace url with c:url tag

Tags: regex

I have a problem to build good regular expressions to find and replace. I need to replace all urls in many `.jsf` files. I want replace ulrs staring by `XXX` with `<c:url value="URL_WITHOUT_XXX"/>`. Examples below.

I stuck with find regular expression `"XXX(.*)"` and replace expression `"<c:url value="\1"/>"`, but my find expression match to long string , for example `"XXX/a" style=""`, but need that match only to first `"` (href end). Anybody helps ?

I have:

```
<a href="XXX/a" style="">
<a href="XXX/b" >
<a href="XXX/c" ...>
```

I want:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/a"/>" style="">
<a href="<c:url value="/b"/>" >
<a href="<c:url value="/c"/>" ...>
```

PS: Sorry for my poor english ;)

**Edit:**
I use Find/Replace in Eclipse (regular expressions on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the language you're working with.

The following regex will match what you want:

```
<a href="XXX[^\"]*"
```

If you want to have some particular value, you can group the regex according to your needs. For example:

```
<a href="(XXX[^\"]*)"
```

will give you in the first group:

```
XXX/a
XXX/b
XXX/b
```

If you want to have only `/a`, `/b`, and `/c`, you can group it like that:

```
<a href="XXX([^\"]*)"
```

**Edit:**
I will explain what `<a href="XXX[^\"]*"` does:

- It will match: `<a href="XXX`
- Then it should match *anything* that except a `"` zero or many times: `[^\"]*`
- Finally match the `"`, which is not really necessary

When you do: `[^abc]` you're telling it to match anything but not `a`, or `b`, or `c`.
So `[^\"]` is: Match anything except a `"`.

And the quantifier `*` means zero or more times, so `a*` will match either an empty string, or `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, ...

And the last thing: *Groups*

When you want to keep the value appart from the entire match, so you can do anything with it, you can use groups: `(something)`.

Comment: it's works great but didn't understand the logic ?? `[^]` means negation but after that it will select `XXX/a` how?? is there no way to select just between href tag like using `^` and `$`

Comment: @Oscar i tried with this http://rubular.com/r/TxmEZEXQU3 , please tell me where i m wrong??

Comment: @diEcho I will modify my answer so you can understand what is the idea.

Comment: @diEcho I edited it. `^` means the begining of the text and `$` the end, so those are kind of useless in this context.

Comment: You don't have to escape the `"` in the char class `[..]`. Details.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. find: `"XXX([^\"]*)"` , replace: `"<c:url value="\1"/>"` - works for me in eclipse and get what i need :)